# IOS-How to do detect if Core Data PersistantStoreCoordinator is accessible or not

Tags: ios, core-data, savechanges

I am trying to find out whether my core data database is accessible in the background when I try to perform some operations.

For this,I am trying to call the saveContext and checking the error object.

```
[[PersistantStoreManager sharedInstance] saveContext:^(NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);
                    }
                }];
```

But I am not sure about the exact error code that system throws when the database is not accessible?
Can anyone please help me proper error code for this?

Is there any other way to know whether data database is accessible or not?

Comment: Why would the persistent store be inaccessible? There's no standard check for accessibility because it isn't something apps normally need to do. What situations cause you to need this check?

Comment: Say if the device is locked!!